# (Flutter) Displaying data of a List in different groups in UI

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list (which is from a database table) like this:
(Note: I have already de-serialized the List)

```
groupNo | Sales
---------------
  1        5
  1        1  
  1        3
  2        6  
  2        9  
  2        2
  2        1  
  3        8  
  3        3  
  4        4  
  4        1  
  4        6  
  4        0  
  4        4  
  4        1
```

Now I want to display this data like this:
[image]

What's the best way of displaying this in the UI?

Comment: Please add the code you have got so far

Comment: @LeonardArnold I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say the List is called `itemList`

First we need a list for number of groups. Since group number is repeated in the `itemList`, using it directly to build cards for each group won't work. So we can add all `groupNo` from `itemList` to a `Set`(Since a Set will remove all duplicate values).

We first declare a `Set`

```
Set groupSet = Set();
```

After that we create a `readGroup()` function which will be declared in `initState`

```
readGroup() {
  setState((){  
   itemList.forEach((item){
     groupSet.add(item.groupNo);
     });
    });
   }
```

Now we will use `ListView.builder` to create a card for each group. Inside the builder, we will use the `for` loop to populate items of each group in their respective cards.

**Note:** We don't use group number from `Set` since the order of item in `Set` is not guaranteed. Thus instead we use `index + 1`.

```
ListView.builder(
 itemCount: groupSet.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
   return Column( children:<Widget>[
   Text("Group "+ (index + 1).toString()),
    SizedBox(height:10),
     Row(children: <Widget>[
      for(item in List) if(item.groupNo = index + 1)  
       Text(item.sales)
       ]);
      ]);
     }
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

(I know I'm too late. But let this solution will definitely help others)

It's a simple thing because **Flutter Pub.dev** just introduced a Library called => **grouped_list**.
Just go through this link. https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list#-example-tab-
Cause this made my day and it is gonna help you too. Enjoy Flutter

Comment: Is it for me or the package has performance issue? The list lags very badly.

Comment: it was okay for me. no lag at all @abrsh